# How to check multiple conditions on dataframe columns, row by row, without using a loop Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I have a big dataframe df that I need to clean from bad data using four different conditions:

1. if the element of column `A` is a number
2. if this number is different from `nan`
3. if the element of column `B` belongs to `list1`
4. if the element of column `C` belongs to `list2`

I would like to check these conditions without a loop because it runs very slowly.
This is the code I wrote:

```
df1=pd.read_csv(data1)
list1=pd.read_csv(data2)
list2=pd.read_csv(data3)
col_df= #list of target column names (it's not important to specify what they are)
df2=pd.DataFrame(np.zeros(shape=(1,len(col_df))),columns=col_df)
row_df3=pd.DataFrame(np.zeros(shape=(1,len(col_df))),columns=col_df) #I use it to append new zero row to previous
k1=0 #index to add new row to df2
for j in range(len(df1)):
        try:
            float(df1['A'][j])
            check=1
        except:
            check=0
        if check==1: #if the element is a number
            if df1['B'][j] in list1['B'].unique(): #if the element is in the first list
                if str(df1['A'][j])!='nan': #if the element value is different from nan
                    if da['C'][j] in list2['C'].unique(): #if the element is in the second list
                        iii=list1.index[list1['B']==df1['B'][j]] #I take the index in list1
                        iii=iii[0]
                        df2.loc[k1]=row_df2.loc[0] #new zero row
                        df2.loc[k1]=df1.iloc[j] #assign elements to new df2 with same column name of df1
                        df2['B'][k1]=list1['B'][iii] #assign element from list1
                        k1=k1+1 #new row for df2
```

It works but slowly. Is there a way to write all this conditions without using a loop? If yes I also thought to use `drop` function instead of creating a new dataframe `df2`.

Thank you in advance!

I tried to do this:

```
def is_float(element: any) -> bool:
    #If you expect None to be passed:
    if element is None: 
        return False
    try:
        float(element)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
df1['Bool']=df1['A'].apply(is_float) #to create a new column that check if it's a number
df2=df1[df1['Bool']==True and df1['B'] in list1['B'].unique() and da['C'] in list2['C'].unique()] #to check all other conditions
```

without defining `df2` previous this time, but it doesn't work.. I get two errors:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

and if I erase the first condition, so

```
df2=df1[df1['B'] in list1['B'].unique() and da['C'] in list2['C'].unique()]
```

I get:

> ValueError: ('Lengths must match to compare')

Comment: can you add the first couple of rows of your data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using apply and those functions you should be able to make a column grouping all conditions together

```
def is_null(value):
    # Null values are considered as float but nan is not equal to nan
    if pd.isna(value):
        return True 
    else: 
        return False

def is_float(value):
    if type(value) == float:
        return True 
    else: 
        return False

def in_list1(value):
    if value in list1: 
        return True 
    else: 
        return False 

def in_list2(value):
    if value in list2: 
        return True 
    else: 
        return False
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll try and later I'll tell you the result

Answer (score 0):

Well, it works perfectly! Code execution time on each dataframe went from 5 hours to 3 minutes! I used the idea of function like this:

```
def func(value):
if value['B'] in list1['B'].unique():
    if value['C'] in list2['C'].unique():
        check=0
        try:
            float(value['A'])
            check=1
        except:
            check=0
        if check==1:        
            if str(value['A'])!='nan': #all condition are satisfied   
                iii=list1.index[list1['B']==value['B']]
                iii=iii[0]
                value['B']=list1['B'][iii]              
                value['Check']=True                      
                return value
            else:
                
                value['Check']=False
                return value
        else:
            
            value['Check']=False
            return value
    else:
        
        value['Check']=False
        return value
else:
    
    value['Check']=False
    return value
df1=pd.read_csv(data1) #read data
df1.insert(loc=7, column='B', value=0) #insert column to assign list1 value 
df1['Check']=0 #new column to check the conditional statements
list1=pd.read_csv(data2) #read list1
list2=pd.read_csv(data3) #read list2
df1=df1.apply(func,axis=1) #apply function which replaces each row with the new one processed
df1=df1[df1['Check']==True] #select all rows which satisfy The conditional statement
df1=df1.drop('Check',axis=1) #drop the check column after use
```

I decided to post it so maybe it can be useful to someone. Thank you very much @Marc